# Remember User Input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm fairly new to javascript, and I am trying to teach myself by making a chrome extension.

I am trying to make an extension that a user can input an activity for each day. At the current moment I only have the activity name as an input field. This is a very simple extension; I'm trying to get into development.

First the user clicks on one of seven buttons for a day of the week.

If there hasn't been an activity name set yet, a message tells the user this, and an input box is displayed. The user types in the name of the activity, and clicks a submit button. What the user inputs is then displayed to the user.

My problem is that when I input an activity name for Monday, it works fine - when I do Tuesday, the activity for Monday is lost. Even when I click on the Monday button, I can't see the activity name I put in for that day.

Anybody see what I'm doing wrong, or any advice? Any help would be greatly appreciated! 
Also is there a way to make it so the input isn't lost at all? Whenever I click on the extension it sets the variables back to their initial setting.

Please and thank you!

My manifest.json file:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Activity... Thingy",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "My first Chrome extension.",



"browser_action": {  
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<style type="text/css">

  body {

    min-width: 560px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    font-family: Georgia;

  }

  .box {

    margin: 2px;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 75px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #542437;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    border: 0px;
    font-family: "Courier New",Courier,"Lucida Sans Typewriter","Lucida Typewriter",monospace;

  }

  .box:hover {

    background-color: #b34600;

  }

  .inputForms {

    display: none;

  }

</style>



</head>

<body>

<button class="box" id="Mon">Mon</button>
<button class="box" id="Tue">Tue</button>
<button class="box" id="Wed">Wed</button>
<button class="box" id="Thr">Thu</button>
<button class="box" id="Fri">Fri</button>
<button class="box" id="Sat">Sat</button>    
<button class="box" id="Sun">Sun</button>

<br /><br />
<br /><br />

<hr />

<p style="font-size: 1.5em;">Click a day of the week to view the current activities set!       </p>

<p id="demo"></p>


<form class="inputForms" id="inputForms">
  Activity Name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="activityName" id="userActivityName">
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn">

</form>

<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

My Javascript file:

```
var monActName = "None set";
var tueActName = "None set";
var userInput;

document.getElementById("Mon").addEventListener("click", function(){

if(monActName != "None set"){

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= monActName;

}

else{

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="You have not set an activity!";

 document.getElementById("inputForms").style.display = "block";

 document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){


   userInput = document.getElementById("userActivityName").value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userInput;
   monActName = userInput;


   });




 }

});

document.getElementById("Tue").addEventListener("click", function(){

if(tueActName != "None set"){

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= tueActName;

}

else{

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="You have not set an activity!";

 document.getElementById("inputForms").style.display = "block";

 document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){


   userInput = document.getElementById("userActivityName").value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = userInput;
   tueActName = userInput;


   });




}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What do you need

To do what you want **you'll need to use `localStorage`**, which is an object that stays memorized in the browser even if the page is reloaded (more informations about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)). This will allow you to have your "activities" always stored, so you'll not lose them.

Then, you will use some basic logic to get your program to work. The basic behavior will be:

1. You load previous set activities from the `localStorage` (if there are any)
2. The user clicks a day
3. You check if the activity for that day is set

   - If it is set, then you output *"Activity for *dayname*: ..."*
   - Otherwise you will:

     1. Output the phrase *"No activity set for *dayname* yet"*
     2. Display the form so the user can input a new activity
     3. Now the user clicks the submit button
     4. Save the activity for that day on `localStorage`
     5. Hide the form, and output *"Activity for *dayname* set!"*

### Storage method

Coming to the storage part, you'll need an object to store the activities, something that will look like this:

```
activities = {
    "Monday": "Some activity",
    "Tuesday": "Some other activity",
    ...
    // and so on        
}
```

Since that **`localStorage` only stores strings**, and not objects, you'll need to use `JSON.stringify` to turn the object in a string and save it, and `JSON.parse` to get the object from the string saved in `localStorage`.

### Write some better HTML

I noticed that some little things can be changed in your page, for example the IDs of the days. This will allow to show the full day name to the user in an easier way (and also save it to localStorage in a more readable format). Here's the change I made:

```
<button class="box" id="Monday">Mon</button> 
<button class="box" id="Tuesday">Tue</button> 
<button class="box" id="Wednesday">Wed</button> 
<!-- and so on... -->
```

Plus, I also changed the text in the submit button to something more comprehensible:

```
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Set activity" id="submitBtn" />
```

There are some other things that can be improved, but it works fine, it's not necessary to do more.

### Implementation

I added a listener to the `<html>` element, which will catch all the events happening inside the page, then inside it I'm checking if the `e.target`, which is the clicked element, is one of the days (with a for loop) or the submit button. If it is one of the days I'll check if there are activities, otherwise I will display the form. If it is the submit button, I will set the activity for the day that has been previously clicked (which is stored in selectedDay). I added a lot of comments to make it easier for you to understand my code. Here is what you were looking for:

```
var days            = document.getElementsByClassName('box'),     // days buttons
    demo            = document.getElementById('demo'),            // text to display to the user
    form            = document.getElementById('inputForms'),      // form with the input and the button
    activityName    = document.getElementById('userActivityName'),// activity input
    submit          = document.getElementById('submitBtn'),       // submit button
    activities      = JSON.parse(localStorage.activities || "{}"),// activities object
                                // ^ if this exists, use it, otherwise create a new empty object "{}"
    selectedDay     = null;                                       // selected day (at the beginning is null)

document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    for (var i=0, day; day = days[i]; i++) { // check if the clicked element is one of the days
        if (e.target == day) { 
            // yes, it is one of the days
            if (!activities[day.id]) { // check the activity
                // the activity for that day has not been set
                demo.textContent = 'You have not set any activity for ' + day.id + ' yet!';
                selectedDay = day.id;
                form.style.display = 'initial';
                // output the string, display the form, and set the selected day
            } else {
                // the activity for that day has been set
                form.style.display = 'none';
                demo.textContent = 'Activity for ' + day.id + ': ' + activities[day.id];
                // output the string, and hide the form if it wasn't hidden
            }
        }
    }

    if (e.target == submit) { // check if the clicked element is the submit button
        activities[selectedDay] = activityName.value; // set the activity for the selected day
        localStorage.activities = JSON.stringify(activities); // save to localStorage
        demo.textContent = 'Activity set for ' + selectedDay + '!'; // output success string
    }
});
```

### Working example

I created a working example of this extension which you can find **[HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/download/3a4c6y1i5slzrye/extension-27870101.zip)**.

Comment: That was a lot more than I was expecting! Thank you!!! And yes I could have done better to make things clearer to the user, I coded this in an hour, so I didn't bother to get too much into the design yet.
Thank you so much I appreciate it, I'll take a look

Comment: chrome.storage can be used instead of localstorage, for example if you want the input to be synced to all the user's Chrome instances, and also can store objects

Comment: Is there also a way to remove the variable from the local storage/ chrome storage? So if a user wants to reset the recipes for the week?
I've tried several different methods, I created a reset button and then did:
if(e.target == reset){
  ....
}
I've tried localStorage.clear(), localStorage.removeItem(), etc. I can't seem to make the variable be forgotten

Comment: @sandi Yes, to remove the variable you can just use `delete`. For example: `delete localStorage.activities`.

Comment: Hmmm, it doesn't appear to be working. This is exactly what I did. I added a variable, set to the ID of the reset button I made. I then have the code: 'if (e.target == reset) {
    
      delete localStorage.activities;
      
      demo.textContent = 'Reset the activities!';
    
    
    }' I know the event is being picked up on, because the demo paragraph is being changed, but the variable is still being remembered. And I have reloaded the extension

Comment: @sandi oh yes, you'll have to clear the activities object too, so you'll need to: `localStorage.activities = "{}"; activities = new Object();` (you don't need `delete` at all).